# QDir::SetSorting Doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, directory, qdir

I have a problem with QDir, I have this folder with lots of images, and I need to iterate through them but, they have to be sorted, so, I'm using `setSorting(QDir::Name)` however, It doesn't work on **Ubuntu**. When I iterate it with QDirIterator it selects pictures in given folder randomly. The weird thing is I use the same exact code on Windows (minGW or MSVC) and It works perfectly.

```
someClass::someClass(QDir dir) {
     m_dir = dir;
     m_directory.setSorting(QDir::Name);
     QStringList filter;
     filter << QString("*.") + format << QString("*.") + "jpg";
     m_dir.setNameFilters(filter);
}
someClass::iterateDir() {
     QDirIterator it(m_dir);
     while(it.hasNext()) {
         it.next();
         qDebug() << it.fileName();

         //analayze the picture here
     }
}
```

here `it.fileName()` should print (0.jpeg, 1.jpeg .... 3000.jpeg) but instead it prints (2342.jpg, 1286.jpg, 684.jpg ... 712.jpg) I tried to use other `sortFlags` (`QDir::Size, QDir::LocaleAware`) but none of them works on Ubuntu. 
Is there something I'm missing? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing 2 variables: `m_dir` and `m_directory`. I assume it's typo and you mean to use the same variable.

`QDirIterator` does not support sorting. `QDir::setSorting()` only affects the list returned by `QDIr:: entryInfoList()` and `QDir:: entryList()`. Use either of them for sorted iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, Yes, that was a typo,  When I use QDirIterator on Windows I always get the pictures in sorted manner. I was using entryList before but it's very slow compared to QDirIterator is there a fast way to iterate through directories?