# QDirIterator sorting in folder

Tags: qt, cross-platform

I'm constructing a QDirIterator with a specific directory. The files inside look like this:

```
file_0
files_1
file_2
.
.
.
.
```

if I use Windows, the iteration is normal, but if I use Linux, the order is different:

```
file_0
file_1
file_10
file_100
.
.
.
file_2
file_20
.
.
```

This is the code:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    QString tmp = it.next();
}
```

I need the Windows type of iteration. How can I control that?
How come it works differently in different operating systems (cross-platform)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QDir::SetSorting Doesn't work on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965919/qdirsetsorting-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It's still cross platform, and does exactly what it [claims to do](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html). Which is iterate over entries in a directory.

You're expecting sorted results, which isn't part of the specified behavior. The difference is likely because the file systems are different (NTFS vs EXT3/4), and organize the underlying inodes in different ways.

If you want standardized behavior you can follow Mohammad's link  in the comment or sort them yourself by throwing them into a QStringList [and calling sort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#sort).